# Do CMake's find_<something> commands traverse symlinks?

Tags: cmake, symlink-traversal

I'm writing a `Find<library>.cmake` module, because no good one exists for the library in question.  This necessitates usage of the [`find_path`](http://devdocs.io/cmake~3.6/command/find_path) and [`find_library`](http://devdocs.io/cmake~3.6/command/find_library) commands.  I'm testing it on macOS El Capitan.

Through means that are not relevant to this question, I determine that on macOS, this library is installed in `/usr/local/opt/<brew formula name>`, which is in fact a symlink to somewhere else (the exact location isn't relevant).  Let's call this path `MYLIB_BREW_ROOT`.

The headers and dylib's for this formula are available in `${MYLIB_BREW_ROOT}/include` and `${MYLIB_BREW_ROOT}/lib`, respectively.  I add these paths, as written here, to the relevant `find` command search paths. **So why isn't CMake finding them?**  *Does CMake traverse symlinks?  If so, how do I enable it?  If not, how do I work around it?*

Comment: Where is the Find<library>.cmake script located?

Comment: @RobertPrévost In the `cmake` directory of a project of mine that's using it.  That is, its path is `<Project>/cmake/Find<Library>.cmake`.

Comment: By using find_path and find_library are you able to update CMAKE_MODULE_PATH before you call find_package(<Library>...)?

Comment: @RobertPrévost Are you asking if my `Find<library>.cmake` is being called in the first place?  If so, it definitely is; I can get printout just fine, and I can even find libraries and headers *not* referred to via symlink.

Comment: I would expect CMake to just `open()` directory *${MYLIB_BREW_ROOT}/include*, and then search inside it. So, whether path to directory contains symlinks or not is opaque for CMake - it is OS who should care about opening such path. Please, provide [mcve]: `CMakeLists.txt` file which contains `find_path()` call and path to the file which is intended to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer is yes.  Symlinks work exactly as I expected them to.  The *real* problem I had was unrelated to CMake; it had to do with pkg-config and the relevant libraries not having entries for it.